# Название связного поля в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Скажите пожалуйста корректна ли будет строка.
Есть таблица owners с полями id, name.
Есть таблица pets с полями owner_id, pet_id, pet_name.
Связывать будем по id владельца.

```
CREATE TABLE owners (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
...
);
CREATE TABLE pets (
pet_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
owner_id INT NOT NULL,
...
FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners(id)
);
```

Comment: Вы о какой строке ?

Comment: @Mike, о той где FK

Comment: С виду корректна. А зачем собственно спрашиваете. MySQL это скормите он скажет если что не так

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо

Comment: @Mike, последний вопрос. Если я вывожу все поля обоих таблиц и мне нету смысла выдеть id владельца два раза. Какон из полей корректное оставлять id ( из owners) или owner_id(из  pets) ведь второй является внешним ключом, то есть ссылаеться на первый, и это - одно и тоже. Какой бы оставили Вы

Comment: думаю из таблицы которая будет первой в запросе, хотя это и не имеет никакого значения

Comment: премного Вам благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скормил все это MySQL Client все работает корректно.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/114640)

Comment: @Naumov это как раз таки ответ

Comment: @Alex ответ должен быть содержательным а не на подобие "ну вот эту штуку просто туда впихнуть"

Comment: @Naumov вопрос  "Скажите пожалуйста корректна ли будет строка", ответ "все работает корректно", по таким вопросам возможны варианты ответов - **да** или **нет** ) Странно, что такой вопрос вообще прозвучал, но это уже дело второе.